# Python Main Thread Function Not Executing Unless GUI Generated on Main Thread is Closed

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, customtkinter

I am developing a desktop application that will eventually pull weather data based on a set of photographs. Currently, I am building the GUI interface to provide the directory of the photo set, analyze the photos for the earliest and latest date then populate the GUI start and end date calendar inputs. There are two GUIs. The main GUI, then a secondary GUI that is run on another thread to show the progress of the photo files being analyzed.

Problem - Currently, the earliest and latest dates will not print (see function choose_directoy(self) under the AppTabView class in file season_weather.py UNTIL the main GUI AppTabView is closed. It is my understanding this is happening because of the print function being on the main thread.

My question - How do I execute the above print(dates) function without closing the GUI?

"season_weather.py"

```
#Generate the app GUI

#Sets the appearance mode of the application
#Options: system(default), light, dark
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

#Sets the color of the widgets
#Supported themes: green, dark-blue, blue
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

#initalize the variable to carry the directory holding the photos for analysis
photoDirectory = ''

#Create app

class AppTabView(ctk.CTkTabview):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        #create the tabs
        self.add("Weather Analysis")
        self.add("Photo Filter")

        # set the tabs to left margin
        self._segmented_button.grid(sticky="W")

        #add widgets to the Weather Analysis tab
        # Weather Station Label
        self.stationLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text='WeatherStation', master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.stationLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='ew')

        # Weather Station Entry Field
        self.stationEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(placeholder_text='Enter the WUnderground Personal Weather Station ID', width=350,
                                         master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.stationEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=20, sticky='ew')

        # Add Hyperlink to WUnderground WunderMap that allows user to find desired weather station name
        # Website is https://www.wunderground.com/wundermap
        # Make a note to user that they are looking for the STATION ID
        self.wundermapLink = ctk.CTkLabel(text = 'WunderMap Station ID', cursor='hand2',
                                          font=('Arial',16,'underline'), text_color='blue', master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.wundermapLink.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)
        self.wundermapLink.bind('<Button-1>',
                                lambda x: webbrowser.open_new('https://www.wunderground.com/wundermap'))
        self.wundermapTip = ctk.CTkLabel(text='Tip: Zoom into the WunderMap to see more available stations.',
                                         font=('Arial', 14), master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.wundermapTip.grid(row=2, column=1)

        #Entry field to choose start date of weather data to pull from weather underground
        #Entry field to choose end date of weather data to pull from weather underground

        #button field to load the chosen directory
        #photos, then suggest to user to pull weather day for at least one day before and after the first and
        # last photo to ensure enough data for analysis
        self.photoDirectoryButton = ctk.CTkButton(text='Choose Directory of Photos', command=self.choose_directory,
                                                  master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.photoDirectoryButton.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        #entry field to show the chosen path
        self.directoryEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(width=350, master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.directoryEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, stick='ew')

        #check box to determine if weather data is pulled based on photo dates, or set dates by user.
        # If checked yes to use photo dates, disable the date entry fields

        # self.photoDateCheck = ctk.CTkCheckBox(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), command=self.activateCalendars,
        #                                       text='Pull Weather Based on First and Last Photo Taken?')
        # self.photoDateCheck.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
        # self.photoDateCheck.deselect()
        self.photoDateLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"),
                                           text='Choose the start and end date of weather data to collect. '
                                                'If a directory of photos is selected, the start and end date '
                                                'is automatically selected', wraplength=300)
        self.photoDateLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        #entry field for choosing start and end date of weather data
        self.startDateLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text="Choose Start Date for Weather Data",
                                           master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.startDateLabel.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.endDateLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text="Choose End Date for Weather Data", master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.endDateLabel.grid(row=7, column=0)
        self.startCalendar = DateEntry(selectmode='day', font=('Arial', 16), date_pattern='yyyy-m-d',
                                       master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.startCalendar.grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.endCalendar = DateEntry(selectmode='day', font=('Arial', 16), date_pattern='yyyy-m-d',
                                     master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.endCalendar.grid(row=8, column=0)

        #set the calendars default to empty entry
        self.startCalendar.delete(0,"end")
        self.endCalendar.delete(0,"end")

        #button for analyzing weather data for photos


        #button for storing weather data for future use

        #Placeholder for Photo Filter Tab widgets
        self.photoFilterDirectoryButton = ctk.CTkButton(text='Choose Directory of Photos', command=self.choose_directory,
                                                  master=self.tab("Photo Filter"))
        self.photoFilterDirectoryButton.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.photoFilterdirectoryEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(width=350, master=self.tab("Photo Filter"))
        self.photoFilterdirectoryEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.photoTimeCheck = ctk.CTkCheckBox(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), text='Analyze Photos Between Two Specific Times')
        self.photoTimeCheck.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.photoTimeCheck.select()

        #build the spinboxes for start and end times
        self.startTimeEntryHoursLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text="Start Hour", master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.startTimeEntryHoursLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(20,0), sticky='w')
        self.startTimeEntryHours = ttk.Spinbox(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), from_=0, to=24, width=3, font=('Arial', 16))
        self.startTimeEntryHours.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=(40,0), sticky='w')
        self.timeColonLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text=":", master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
        self.timeColonLabel.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=(87,0), sticky='w')
        self.startTimeEntryMinutesLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text="Start Minutes", master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.startTimeEntryMinutesLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(90,0), sticky='w')
        self.startTimeEntryMinutes = ttk.Spinbox(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), from_=0, to=59, width=3,
                                           font=('Arial', 16))
        self.startTimeEntryMinutes.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=(130, 0), sticky='w')
        self.startTimeEntryHours.set(5)
        self.startTimeEntryMinutes.set(0)

        self.endTimeEntryHoursLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text="End Hour", master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.endTimeEntryHoursLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(0, 100), sticky='e')
        self.endTimeEntryHours = ttk.Spinbox(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), from_=0, to=24, width=3,
                                           font=('Arial', 16))
        self.endTimeEntryHours.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=(0, 130), sticky='e')
        self.endTimeColonLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text=":", master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
        self.endTimeColonLabel.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=(0, 87), sticky='e')
        self.endTimeEntryMinutesLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(text="End Minutes", master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"))
        self.endTimeEntryMinutesLabel.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(0, 15), sticky='e')
        self.endTimeEntryMinutes = ttk.Spinbox(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), from_=0, to=59, width=3,
                                             font=('Arial', 16))
        self.endTimeEntryMinutes.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=(0, 40), sticky='e')
        self.endTimeEntryHours.set(20)
        self.endTimeEntryMinutes.set(0)

        # check boxes to store weather data only, or analyze photos
        self.weatherPhotoToggleSwitch = ctk.CTkSwitch(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), text='Analyze Photos')
        self.weatherPhotoToggleSwitch.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=(125,0))
        self.weatherAnalyzeLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), text='Store Weather Data Only')
        self.weatherAnalyzeLabel.grid(row=8, column=1, padx=(50,0), sticky='w')

        # create button to run the selected analysis configuration
        self.runButton = ctk.CTkButton(master=self.tab("Weather Analysis"), text="RUN", command=self.run)
        self.runButton.grid(row=9, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

    def choose_directory(self):
        photo_directory = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Choose a Directory", initialdir="/")

        if photo_directory:
            global photoDirectory
            self.directoryEntry.insert(0, photo_directory)
            # self.photoDateCheck.select()
            dates = util.find_earliest_and_latest_dates(photo_directory)
            # set the start and end dates to one day before and after the first and last photo. This ensures enough weather
            # data is collected to complete all analysis
            print(dates)
            # self.startCalendar.set_date(dates[0])
            # self.endCalendar.set_date(dates[1])






    # def activateCalendars(self):
    #
    #     if self.photoDateCheck.get() == 1:
    #         self.startCalendar.delete(0, "end")
    #         self.endCalendar.delete(0, "end")

    def run(self):
        if self.weatherPhotoToggleSwitch.get() == 0:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=get_weather, args=(self.startCalendar.get_date(),
                                                                self.endCalendar.get_date(), self.stationEntry.get()))
            # get_weather(self.startCalendar.get_date(), self.endCalendar.get_date(), self.stationEntry.get())
            thread.start()
            #FUNCTION IS HANGING. THREADING IS NEEDED TO RUN THE FUNCTION ON OWN THREAD. NEED TO PRINT THIS THREAD TO CONSOLE
            # threading does not show up on output console, and doesn't seem to be running.
        if self.weatherPhotoToggleSwitch.get() == 1:
           pass
           #run command to get weather data function, then run a separate function to analyze the weather data.


class App(ctk.CTk):
    #Layout of the GUI will be written in the init itself
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #set the title of our window to "Camera Trap Weather Study"
        self.title("Camera Trap Tools")
        #Set dimensions of the window
        # self.geometry("900x400")
        self.tab_view = AppTabView(master=self)
        self.tab_view.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    # Runs the app
    app.mainloop()"""
```

"util.py"

```
class CustomThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, verbose=None):
        Thread.__init__(self, group, target, name, args, kwargs)
        self._return = None

    def run(self):
        if self._target is not None:
            self._return = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

    def join(self):
        Thread.join(self)
        return self._return
def get_photo_taken_time(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        tags = exifread.process_file(f, stop_tag="EXIF DateTimeOriginal")
        if "EXIF DateTimeOriginal" in tags:
            taken_time = tags["EXIF DateTimeOriginal"]
            return datetime.strptime(str(taken_time), "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
    return None

def copy_photos_between_times(source_dir, dest_dir, start_time, end_time):
    if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
        os.makedirs(dest_dir)

    for entry in os.scandir(source_dir):
        if entry.is_file():
            file_time = get_photo_taken_time(entry.path)
            if file_time and start_time <= file_time.time() <= end_time:
                dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, entry.name)
                shutil.copy2(entry.path, dest_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_directory = "C:/Users/antho/Hunting/Deer/2022-2023/Stanleys/South Stand"
    destination_directory = "C:/Users/antho/Hunting/Deer/2022-2023/Stanleys/South Stand/DAYTIME"
    start_time = time(5, 0, 0)
    end_time = time(20, 0, 0)

    copy_photos_between_times(source_directory, destination_directory, start_time, end_time)
    print("Copying photos complete")


def get_date_taken(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            tags = exifread.process_file(f, details=False)
            date_tag = tags.get('EXIF DateTimeOriginal') or tags.get('Image DateTime')
            if date_tag:
                date_str = str(date_tag)
                return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading EXIF data for {file_path}: {e}")
    return None


#todo need to run the progress bar on a separate thread so the user can minimize the GUI if desired
def find_earliest_and_latest_dates(photo_dir):
    photo_files = [f for f in os.listdir(photo_dir) if
                   f.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp', '.tiff'))]

    if not photo_files:
        return None, None

    # earliest_date = None
    # latest_date = None
    total_files = len(photo_files)

    print('Analyzing ' + str(total_files) + ' photos')

    # create a customtkinter window
    top = ctk.CTkToplevel()
    top.title("SCANNING PHOTOS METADATA")
    top.geometry("600x100")

    # Create a progress bar
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(top, length=300, mode='determinate')
    progress_bar.pack(pady=10)

    # Create a label ti display progress
    progress_label = tk.Label(top, text='')
    progress_label.pack()

    top.update()  # Needed to display the window initially

    top.after(100)

    #update the progress bar and label
    def update_progress(current_file):
        progress = (current_file + 1) / total_files * 100
        progress_bar['value'] = progress
        progress_label.configure(text=f"Analyzing file {current_file + 1} of {total_files}")
        top.update_idletasks() # Force GUI Update


    def process_photos():
        earliest_date = None
        latest_date = None
    # for photo_file in tqdm(photo_files):
        for i, photo_file in enumerate(photo_files):
            file_path = os.path.join(photo_dir, photo_file)
            date_taken = get_date_taken(file_path)

            if date_taken:
                if earliest_date is None or date_taken < earliest_date:
                    earliest_date = date_taken
                if latest_date is None or date_taken > latest_date:
                    latest_date = date_taken

            update_progress(i)

        top.destroy()

        print('Analysis complete')

        return datetime.date(earliest_date), datetime.date(latest_date)

    # result_event = threading.Event()

    def thread_function():
        result_photos = process_photos()
        earliest, latest = result_photos
        # result_event.set()

        # print(earliest, latest)
        return earliest, latest
    top.update_idletasks()
    processing_thread = CustomThread(target=thread_function)
    processing_thread.start()

    # todo - earliest and latest dates are not printing until the GUI is closed, because the GUI is running on a second
    #  thread, whereas the print function is on the main thread. How do you transfer the variables to the main thread?

    top.mainloop()
    # If I remove the top.mainloop() from the child, then the child GUI never appears and the app freezes.
    # Look at https://coderslegacy.com/python/get-values-from-toplevel-tkinter-window/ .
    # May need to change code to be class based mirroring the site's example

    return processing_thread.join()
```

Comment: Use `tk.Toplevel()` or `ctk.CTkToplevel()` for child window. Also call `mainloop()` only once, so remove `root.mainloop()` inside `find_earliest_and_latest_dates()`.

Comment: I updated the "util.py" file code above to reflect the change to ```ctk.CTkTopLevel()``` for the child window. I also attempted to remove ```root.mainloop()``` from inside the ```find_earliest_and_latest_dates()```, but doing so caused the main window to freeze. Adding back` ```top.mainloop()``` allows the child GUI window to work, but the dates values still do not return to ```print(dates)``` call.  It sure seems that you are right, it is related to the GUI parent/child, but after spending a day researching I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to run `.mainloop()` only once.  If you want to wait for the completion of the photos processing, suggest to use `.wait_variable()` instead of `.mainloop()`.

Also for your case, you can use `.after()` instead of threading.

Below is the modified `find_earliest_and_latest_dates()`:

```py
def find_earliest_and_latest_dates(photo_dir):
    photo_files = [f for f in os.listdir(photo_dir) if
                   f.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp', '.tiff'))]

    if not photo_files:
        return None, None

    # earliest_date = None
    # latest_date = None
    total_files = len(photo_files)

    print('Analyzing ' + str(total_files) + ' photos')

    # create a customtkinter window
    top = ctk.CTkToplevel()
    top.title("SCANNING PHOTOS METADATA")
    top.geometry("600x100")

    # Create a progress bar
    #progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(top, length=300, mode='determinate')
    progress_bar = ctk.CTkProgressBar(top, width=300, mode='determinate')
    progress_bar.pack(pady=10)

    # Create a label ti display progress
    progress_label = ctk.CTkLabel(top, text='')
    progress_label.pack()

    #update the progress bar and label
    def update_progress(current_file):
        progress = (current_file + 1) / total_files
        progress_bar.set(progress)
        progress_label.configure(text=f"Analyzing file {current_file + 1} of {total_files}")

    def process_photos(i=0):
        file_path = os.path.join(photo_dir, photo_files[i])
        date_taken = get_date_taken(file_path)

        if date_taken:
            if earliest_date is None or date_taken < earliest_date:
                earliest_date = date_taken
            if latest_date is None or date_taken > latest_date:
                latest_date = date_taken

        update_progress(i)

        if i < len(photo_files)-1:
            top.after(5, process_photos, i+1)
        else:
            done.set(True)

    # tkinter variable for notification of photos processing completion
    done = tk.BooleanVar()
    earliest_date = None
    latest_date = None
    process_photos() # start processing photos

    top.transient(tk._get_default_root())
    top.wait_variable(done) # wait for completion of photos processing
    top.destroy()
    print('Analysis complete')

    return earliest_date, latest_date
```